# Access Hardware Information Centrally

Tags: .net, security, active-directory, hardware

Our PC Tech's are having to go around our company and write down information about every PC within the company (OS, CPU Speed, Memory).

Is there any way to gather this information through ASP.Net?  I know you can do it using Winforms, and i know there is also a security risk, but all that aside is it still possible?

Comment: I believe you'd need to embedded an ActiveX control into a web page in order to do this via the web.

Comment: I agree with @Dave - but, it will only work in IE - you could create a small application that does all the work...but then every machine will have to have it downloaded and then ran

Comment: Have you checked to see if Flash or Silverlight has access to that data. Just about everyone has one of those plugins installed already.

Comment: Are they using Active Directory for domain admin? If so, they can create queries for all computers on the domain?

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky We are using AD.  That is definitly something I want to look into...

Comment: Removed [tag:ASP.NET] tag since that wasn't an actual requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, I'd recommend doing a query with AD on your domain. I had to do something similar to see all computers on the domain and who logged in. We created a login script that set the description of the computer to the current user. Anyway, if you'd like to do this, you can try [this link](http://www.petri.co.il/saved_queries_in_windows_2003_dsa.htm) to get some more information on creating the query in AD. HTH